# Q-Q Plots with Countr fits

Tags: r, count, weibull, renewal, qq

I am trying to create Q-Q plots for a Weibull Count fit obtained with Countr.

I am able to fit my data with Countr with the Weibull Distribution. I thought I could try to plot my data against the $fitted.values output created by Countr. Unfortunately, that variable is populated with the repeated of the same number.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give your example but you can obtain the fitted values using `fitted()` on the fitted model object. That said, q-q plots are usually done for residuals, see `residuals()` and `residuals_plot()`.